# How to wait but not block thread when getting a resource in python?

Tags: python, block

Suppose we need to create a database connection pool, the requirement is that when a client tries to get a connection, if all exisiting connections are busy, then need to wait for 30 second before giving up, hope some connections are released by other client. So the naive solution is

```
def get_connection():
    if all_conn_are_busy:
        time.sleep(30)
        try to get connection again
    else:
        return conn
```

But since time.sleep(30) will block the thread, if 2 clients trying to get connection at the same time, it will block for 60 seconds. So is there any way to noblock it but also wait for some time?

Comment: Give each pending connection a timer.  Do your loop with 1 second sleep, and decrement each timer until it goes to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(A.) You have already lost the battle if you're in this "waiting" regime.

(B.) It sounds like you want to have a single thread which is exclusively
dedicated to acquiring that *next* connection.
And if it is *already* busy trying to acquire one,
then 2nd caller should promptly suffer fatal error.

To have dozens of threads all clamoring for next connection
from a terminally overloaded DB server sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Consider pre-allocating connections at some slow rate,
so there is always one available for the next requestor.

Apparently you have some connection pool, and a policy
for discarding idle connections. Re-evaluate how well suited
that policy is in light of your current use cases.